# Word 2010 Crashes - Unknown Module - Only Some Documents

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, crash, microsoft-word-2010

**Situation:**
User has Windows 7 Enterprise x64.  User has Word 2010.  Word opens most documents fine (both .doc and .docx).  There are seemingly random documents that will crash Word with the following error:

> Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 14.0.7160.5000, time stamp: 0x55fc2717
>
> Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x85157bd9
>
> Faulting process id: 0x2e6c
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d1079e71eacb68
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>
> Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE
>
> Faulting module path: unknown
>
> Report Id: b36b0fee-741b-11e5-a505-0026b987f448

**What I know:**
This problem happens with random documents, seemingly received via email attachment.  We are on a domain, and have identical computers for our users.  A different user in the same area as this user, was able to open said documents without issue.

**What I have tried so far**

- The event log referrences some temp files in the user's appdata location, so I have cleared those out.
- Repair install of Office as a whole
- Changing default printer
- Running word in safe mode, and opening the documents

***Anyone have any thoughts?***

Comment: Have you done a memory test and a hard drive surface scan?  Run Windows itself in safe mode? Do these documents work fine on other machines?  What if you open them on another machine, save them, and then reopen them on this machine? Have you tried reinstalling Windows?  The last one is a bit extreme I admit, but you can probably put a new drive in with a clean Windows and Office install to at least rule that out.

Comment: Mem test no, hdd scan, no.  WIndows in safe mode yes.  THey work fine on other machines, tried the saving as new files, tried copying and pasting to a whole new file.  Ended up dropping in a new hdd and reimaging the machine.  Had to burn down the house for the ant problem, but it works for her now.

Answer (score 1):

No resolution.  Unable to pin down the problem to any one area.  Already spent my maximum 2 hour troubleshooting window.  Had to rebuild the machine.  Following a rebuild on a new drive, all tested working.  User was back up and running in about 90 minutes from that point.